# Можно ли вытащить данные вкладки “Network” из консоли браузера

Tags: javascript, jquery

Можно ли вытащить данные вкладки “Network” из консоли браузера

Comment: Подозреваю, что у вас FF. Уточните в вопросе. И в каком контексте ваш JS должен их дергать? Со страницы или из расширения браузера?

Comment: Js должен дергать из расширения браузера

Answer (score 1):

Нет, движок джаваскрипт не предназначен для этого. Если нужно трекать ajax реквесты, можно попробовать переопредлить методы XMLHttpRequest.